# Adding query parameters to an oauth redirect_uri using Django's social_auth

Tags: django, oauth, django-socialauth

In both OAuth 2 and OAuth 1 the redirect URL provided to the authenticating site may contain additional query parameters (as specified in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-3.1.2, and at the top of page 11 in https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5849#section-2.2)

I'm currently using Django with the social-auth app to identify users via OAuth on a website. I would like to keep certain query parameters (e.g. `?next=...`) between the user arriving at the site and the user becoming logged in. django-social-auth can use sessions to persist `?next=...`, and can persist other parameters in the same way ([django social_auth passing extra arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14033520/django-social-auth-passing-extra-arguments)). This seems pretty heavy-weight compared to just forwarding the parameters via the redirect uri. Is it possible to configure social-auth to do this?

Comment: The problem resides with some providers that won't accept your ``redirect_uri`` because of the extra parameters, to keep it simple DSA keeps the parameters in the session.